# Help on making LED Display

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

[image]

Hello! Can anyone help me draw the following symbol for LED Display in LaTeX? Any help or recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I do not know those symbols --- `circuitikz` has [seven segment display](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/eb0c20aa008aee1bb4cbec660fa60f974667a1c6/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#9c)

Comment: I have some tutorials on creating circuitikz components; http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm